# How do I use Charles Proxy to monitor traffic from IE 8 in a virtual box VM?

Tags: javascript, proxy, virtual-machine

I'm trying to debug an issue in IE8.

I'm testing a live bug in the JavaScript code that is minified and uglified, so dev tools are not very useful here.

I'm working on a Mac so I'm using a VirtualBox VM.

I have Charles Proxy running. I want to use Charles to map the served JavaScript to a local unminified version. This is fine for Firefox and Chrome running natively but I cannot get Charles to monitor traffic from the VM.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As it turns out, all I had to do was tell IE in the VM to use my proxy.

Internet Options -> Connections tab, click LAN settings -> Select the Use a proxy server for your LAN check box

In the Address box, type the address of the proxy server, in my case it was the IP of my Mac

In the Port box, type the port number Charles is running on.

Comment: Charles is usually running on in the Port field 8888  
  
  
https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone is confused in choosing the right IP address:

1. find your proxy IP address and port (in Ubuntu go to Network -> Proxy).
2. type obtained values to browser proxy settings as mentions in the [@spinners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626425/spinners) answer.
3. use the proxy IP address to call the host from your VirtualBox's browser.